# Use localhost URL in vuetable-2

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vue-tables-2

I am trying to use [this](https://github.com/ratiw/vuetable-2) component in my project. Below code is working.

```
<template>
    <vuetable 
    ref="vuetable" 
    api-url="https://vuetable.ratiw.net/api/users"
    :fields="['name', 'email']"></vuetable>
</template>
```

But it is not working when I change `api-url` like below

```
<template>
    <vuetable 
    ref="vuetable" 
    api-url="http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/addresses"
    :fields="['name', 'email']"></vuetable>
</template>
```

I am getting error like below.

[image]

I am getting below error while trying trying to browse URL through browser.

[image]

Comment: What is the error you are receiving?

Comment: Thanks @Hamatti. I updated my post with error. Thanks

Comment: it seems like your API requires authentication that you are not providing.

Comment: @Hamatti, thanks for reply. Could you help me in this regard ?

Comment: It seems to be a php problem rather than a frontend problem because your backend application complained that `Route [login] not defined.`